# add tab host with activities inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

Good day. I have some problem.
I have app with listview at left and detail view at right. In right view I have a fragment with tab host. But I also want to add activities for all tabs.
For example:
I have clients list at left.
At right I have tabs: "clients comments", "clients photos", "clients Info"
In clients comments I need in activity with comments for this client, and with possibility to add new comment. 
I have already made a list view and detail, but I have problems with integration tab hosts into it. So what I have. Here My code of detail fragment

```
 public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

        DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;
        private Activity lo_parentAct;



        public ItemDetailFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
                mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);
            if (mItem != null) {
                Intent lv_intent;
            //    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail)).setText(mItem.content);
                TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
                tabHost.setup();

                TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
                spec1.setIndicator("Общая информация");
                lo_parentAct = this.getActivity();
                lv_intent = new Intent(lo_parentAct, ClientInfoActivity.class);

                TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
                spec2.setIndicator("Заметки");
                lv_intent = new Intent(lo_parentAct, ClientCommentsActivity.class);

                TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
                spec3.setIndicator("Фото");
                lv_intent = new Intent(lo_parentAct, ClientPhotosActivity.class);


                tabHost.addTab(spec1);
                tabHost.addTab(spec2);
                tabHost.addTab(spec3);

            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

An the layout

```
    <TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tabHost"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            >
        <TabWidget
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            />
             <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
             >
                 <LinearLayout
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="60px"
                >
             <TextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="100px" 
            android:text="This is tab1"
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            />    

     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="60px"
             >
         <TextView  
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="100px" 
                android:text="This is tab 2"
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                />

     </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tab3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >
             <TextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="100px" 
            android:text="This is tab 3"
            android:id="@+id/txt3"
            />

     </LinearLayout>
     </FrameLayout>

    </TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

> add tab host with activities inside fragment

You can't put activities into fragments! 
As I understand - you want to put `TabActivity` (wich is deprecated) with different `activities` into your main activity's root `Fragment` -  this way is absolutely wrong.

One way to implement what you need is:

1. create one `FragmentActivity`.
2. put TabWidget into root layout of your `FragmentActivity`.
3. then put different `Fragments` into you TabWidget's tabs.

You can look at my similar answer with code examples into another [theme (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347886/replacement-of-tabactivity-with-fragmentactivity-and-fragments/12348482#12348482).

Comment: but if I have "SplitView" application?

Comment: ok you have SplitView application. So what? Can you be more specific?  What do you exactly need? Right now your question is absolutely unclear.

Comment: there is no `SplitView` in andriod. But you can implement iOS like SplitView via android `Fragment`s.

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand. I will try =)