# Cleaning up a Fragment in onDestroy and onDetach

Tags: android, memory-management, fragment

This might sound very basic, but in `onDetach` why/what should I be cleaning up?  If the fragment is being destroyed shouldn't references, such as the Context, be automatically cleaned up for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shouldn't references, such as the Context, be automatically cleaned up
>   for me?

Yes.

> in onDetach why/what should I be cleaning up?

Nothing.  You may go through your entire Android career without ever having a good reason to override this method.

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421945/retained-fragments-with-ui-and-memory-leaks) only referencing retained fragments then?  Also, I"m guessing I should still clean up views though in onDestroyView?  Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Yes.  If your Fragment holds a reference to its Activity (a silly idea, given the Fragment method getActivity()) it should forget it in onDetach.

Comment: I am not sure that this answer is entirely correct. For Fragments, it is possible that onDestroy() is not called. Such is the case when a Fragment is detached, only onPause, onStop and onDestroyView methods are called. In the event that a Fragment is removed, however, its onPause, onStop, onDestroyView, onDestroy and onDetach methods are called. With that being said, I onDestroyView is suggested to add your closing logic to.