# What is the best way to avoid memory leaks in android fragment

Tags: android, memory-leaks, fragment

I found many way to avoid memory leaks in android fragment, but which is the best way?

1.Set the view to null when onDestroyView is called

```
public class LeakyFragment extends Fragment{

    private View mLeak; // retained

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mLeak = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatever, container, false);
        return mLeak;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mLeak = null; // now cleaning up!
    }
}
```

2.Set all the child view = null and remove the view

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView(){
        super.onDestroyView();
        unbindDrawables(mLeak);
    }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view){
        if (view.getBackground() != null){
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView)){
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++){
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
    }
```

Comment: See Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421945/retained-fragments-with-ui-and-memory-leaks?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Setting a variable to `null` does not mean that it will get GC'd. It will only be GC'd if there are no other strong references to it anywhere.

Setting `setRetainInstance(true)` does not make your `Fragment` leak per se, it just preserves that instance of the `Fragment` across configuration changes. It may be considered a "conscious leak", since you are telling the framework you want to retain the `Fragment` object past the current `Activity`'s lifecycle.

Now the `Fragment` will leak your `Activity` if it is not a UI-less `Fragment`. This happens because `Fragments` that have a UI will hold references to UI components(i.e. `TextViews`, `EditTexts`, etc), and these `Views` hold a reference of the `Activity`'s `Context`. In order to avoid this, you need to set all of those references to `null` as you are doing.

Also, you probably also need to remove `mLeak` from its parent as well.

Comment: Any sample to avoid memory leaks? I got out of memory on calling setContentView when i change a fragment in FragmentTabHost.

Comment: You might be trying to load an image that requires too much memory. Are you setting a drawable to an `ImageView`?

Comment: DONT use setRetainInstance.

Comment: You need say what you can do with this layout. Then we can help you.

Comment: why shouldn't he use `setRetainInsance()`  @PedroPauloAmorim?

Comment: The fragment is not setting a drawable, but the xml layout has set some image in the ImageView. Those images about 600kb.

Comment: The amount of disk space an image takes is irrelevant when it comes to how much memory (RAM) the image takes. The amount of RAM an image takes is related to the resolution via the following equation `# of bytes in memory = imageWidth x imageHeight * 4`

Comment: So, the solution is make the resolution of the image more lower?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I would recommend.

Comment: @Emmanuel You need follow the Fragment lifecycle. setRentainInstance() is just a workaround.

Comment: I do not understand why you think it is a workaround? a workaround for what? It is a convenience method for retaining a `Fragment` across configuration changes. I do not see a problem on using it if it is used for the correct reasons.

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim it helps if you use more than a statement but add some in detail explanations!

Comment: So, i should call setRetainInstance(true); in onCreate or other lifecycle?

Comment: If you use `setRetainInstance()` in a `Fragment` that has a UI you will leak the `Activity` if you do not set all the `Views` it references to `null` when the `Fragment` calls `onDestroyView`. I would only use `setRetainInstance()` with `Fragments` that do not have a UI.

Comment: So I should make all of my textviews and imagebuttons null in the `onPause`?

Comment: i have same problem in recyclerview lagging please check my question @Emmanuel 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880908/add-same-fragment-second-time-add-more-then-one-time-fragment-then-recyclervie