# Fragment field is null after rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, rotation, fragment

I have fragment, where I call custom view-class (Dragger)

```
public class CanvasFragment extends Fragment {

    private Dragger dragger;

    public CanvasFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_canvas, container, false);

        dragger = (Dragger) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dragger);

        int[] symbolIndex = {};

        dragger.setElementsArray(symbolIndex);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void addIconToCanvas(int id){
        dragger.addIcon(id);
    }
}
```

and I have another fragment with `RecyclerView` and adapter, in which I call `CanvasFragment's` method `addIconToCanvas()` through the host Activity of `CanvasFragment`.

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private int[] data;
    private Context context;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView itemView;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            itemView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.im_item);
        }
    }

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int[] myDataset) {
        data = myDataset;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.itemView.setImageResource(data[position]);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity)context).addItemToCanvas(data[position]);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.length;
    }
}
```

I found that after rotation `dragger` in `CanvasFragment` gets new reference, but when I call `addIconToCanvas()` from adapter - `dragger` is null.

I really can't understand why field gets reference and then lose it)))

Does anybody knows, what is wrong with that?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: host activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CanvasFragment canvasFragment = new CanvasFragment();
    private ItemsFragment itemsFragment = new ItemsFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container_canvas, canvasFragment)
                .commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container_items, itemsFragment)
                .commit();
        }

    }

    public void addItemToCanvas(int id){
        canvasFragment.addIconToCanvas(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the line

> `private CanvasFragment canvasFragment = new CanvasFragment();`

you assign a new instance of your `Fragment` to the variable *canvasFragment* every time the `Activity` is created. But only if `savedInstanceState == null` you add this instance of CanvasFragment to the UI.

The `Fragment` method `onCreateView()` will only be called if the `Fragment` needs to be shown, so *dragger* remains null for the newly created instance after a configuration change.

What can you do?

Only create an instance of CanvasFragment if you want to add it to the UI. In cases where `savedInstanceState != null`, find the already existing `Fragment` like this:

```
canvasFragment = (CanvasFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_canvas);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line setRetainInstance(true); from your fragments and try.

Comment: this line was added after first crash. So it doesn't make any difference

Comment: In the MainActivity, savedInstanceState will not be null after device orientation change. so the statements inside 'if check' will not be executed after device orientation. can you please post the full code of the activity.

Comment: I've edited question. There's full code of host activity

Comment: Remove the line if(savedInstanceState == null) from the activity and remove the setRetainInstance(true) from both the fragments, and try.

Comment: It could be good way, but it's closer to workaround than solution. But anyway thank you!

Comment: I dont think its a workaround. setRetainInstance(true) should not be used to retain the fragment with UI. It could be used to retain stateless fragment to hold large data after orientation change. So during the orientation change, the fragment must be destroyed and a new fragment must be added after the orientation change. So if(savedInstanceState == null) check must be removed, to add a new fragment after orientation change.

Comment: Well, yes, you're right. IMHO it's better to save state than remove all check's) Vote your answer, man!

Comment: :) Also, using setRetainInstance(true) might lead to Activity leaks. check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13422819/4586742

Answer (score 0):

put this:

```
androidConfigChanges: "keyboardHidden | orientation | screenSize"
```

in your android xml file where the your mainActivity is defined. something like this

```
<activity
android:name="com.projectname.MainActivity"
android:label = "@string/title_activity_main"
</activity>
```

then it should luck like this:

```
<activity
android:name="com.projectname.MainActivity"
androidConfigChanges: "keyboardHidden | orientation | screenSize"
android:label = "@string/title_activity_main"
</activity>
```

Comment: yes. but it helps my keeping the reference to all created objects on screen rotation