# app crashes on second orientation?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using fragments and below is my code. My app crashes when I try to change the orientation more than once.

This is my code:

```
public void Reservation_Dashboardinfo_execute() {

    String url_main = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(
            "Detail_Bundle");
    url = url_main + "&action=getDashboardInfoDay";
    flag = 1;
    updateList clist = new updateList();
    clist.execute(new String[] { url });

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setRetainInstance(true);
    String url_main = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(
            "Detail_Bundle");
    url = url_main + "&action=getDashboardInfoDay";
    updateList clist = new updateList();
    clist.execute(new String[] { url });

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reserv_dashboardinfo, container,
            false);

    return view;
}

class updateList
        extends
        AsyncTask<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
    TableRow row, row_yield, row_status;
    TextView t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        TableLayout tl1;
        tl1 = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.table_dashboard);

        if (flag == 1) {

            tl1 = (TableLayout) getActivity()
                    .findViewById(R.id.table_dashboard);
            tl1.removeAllViews();
            tl1.invalidate();
            row = new TableRow(getActivity());

            t1 = new TextView(getActivity());

            t2 = new TextView(getActivity());

            t3 = new TextView(getActivity());

            t1.setText("Daypart");
            t2.setText("Reservation");
            t3.setText("Guest");
            t1.setTextSize(15);
            t2.setTextSize(15);
            t3.setTextSize(15);
            t1.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
            t2.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
            t3.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);

            row.addView(t1);
            row.addView(t2);
            row.addView(t3);

            tl1.setStretchAllColumns(true);
            tl1.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        }

        for (int current = 0; current < result.size(); current++) {


            row = new TableRow(getActivity());

            t1 = new TextView(getActivity());

            t2 = new TextView(getActivity());

            t3 = new TextView(getActivity());

            t1.setText(result.get(current).get("Daypart"));
            t2.setText(result.get(current).get("Reservation_Today"));
            t3.setText(result.get(current).get("Nop_Today"));

            t1.setTextSize(15);
            t2.setTextSize(15);
            t3.setTextSize(15);

            row.addView(t1);
            row.addView(t2);
            row.addView(t3);

            tl1.setStretchAllColumns(true);
            tl1.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }

        row_yield = new TableRow(getActivity());
        t4 = new TextView(getActivity());

        t5 = new TextView(getActivity());
        t4.setText("Current Yield");
        // String
        // total_seated=getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("total_seated");
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        contactList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getActivity()
                .getIntent().getSerializableExtra("logindetails");

        String maxcapacity = contactList.get(0).get("MaxCapacity");

        int max_value = Integer.parseInt(maxcapacity);
        int total_seated_value = Integer.parseInt("2");
        float yield = (total_seated_value * 100) / max_value;
        t5.setText("" + yield + "% (" + total_seated_value + " seated)");
        t4.setTextSize(15);
        t5.setTextSize(15);
        row_yield.addView(t4);
        row_yield.addView(t5);
        tl1.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        tl1.addView(row_yield, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        row_status = new TableRow(getActivity());
        t6 = new TextView(getActivity());

        t7 = new TextView(getActivity());

        t6.setText("Connection Status");
        Drawable img = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.green_rnd);

        t7.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(img, null, null, null);
        t6.setTextSize(15);

        row_status.addView(t6);
        row_status.addView(t7);
        tl1.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        tl1.addView(row_status, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
            String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url, postParameters);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            contacts = json.getJSONArray("result");

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                // String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String daypart = c.getString("daypart");
                String reservation = c.getString("reservations");
                String reservation7 = c.getString("reservations7");
                String reservation14 = c.getString("reservations14");
                String guests = c.getString("nop");
                String guests7 = c.getString("nop7");
                String guests14 = c.getString("nop14");



                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                // map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put("Daypart", daypart);
                map.put("Reservation_Today", reservation);
                map.put("Reservation_Next7", reservation7);
                map.put("Reservation_Next14", reservation14);
                map.put("Nop_Today", guests);
                map.put("Nop_Next7", guests7);
                map.put("Nop_Next14", guests14);
                // map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                // map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return contactList;
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

this is my logcat

```
03-12 18:49:26.946: E/PhonePolicy(1208): Could not preload class for phone policy:    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
 03-12 18:49:27.036: I/dalvikvm-heap(1208): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.944MB for 3145744-byte allocation
  03-12 18:49:27.296: D/libEGL(1208): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
  03-12 18:49:27.296: D/libEGL(1208): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
   03-12 18:49:27.306: D/libEGL(1208): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
   03-12 18:49:27.346: D/OpenGLRenderer(1208): Enabling debug mode 0
   03-12 18:49:27.856: I/dalvikvm-heap(1208): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.000MB for 3145744-byte allocation
   03-12 18:49:28.006: D/TextLayoutCache(1208): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
   03-12 18:49:28.376: D/OpenGLRenderer(1208): Flushing caches (mode 0)
  03-12 18:49:35.936: V/response code(1208): 200
   03-12 18:49:42.316: D/OpenGLRenderer(1208): Flushing caches (mode 0)
  03-12 18:49:44.226: D/OpenGLRenderer(1208): Flushing caches (mode 0)
  03-12 18:49:44.476: W/PhoneWindow(1208): Previously focused view reported id 2131230886 during save, but can't be found during restore.
  03-12 18:49:46.066: D/AndroidRuntime(1208): Shutting down VM
  03-12 18:49:46.066: W/dalvikvm(1208): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3e1f8)
  03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208): java.lang.NullPointerException
  03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):   at com.demo.fragmentdemo.Reservation_Dashboardinfo$updateList.onPostExecute(Reservation_Dashbo ardinfo.java:116)
  03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):   at com.demo.fragmentdemo.Reservation_Dashboardinfo$updateList.onPostExecute(Reservation_Dashboardinfo.java:1)
  03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
  03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
  03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
  03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4429)
   03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
   03-12 18:49:46.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1208):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
```

I am unable to understand my mistake. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: this question is quite old and i figured it out so how to close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a NPE (null pointer exception) at your Asynctask. Something (a pointer) which shouldn't be null, is.

Also since you are using fragments you should retain the data on rotation, [either by saving them in the `onSavedInstance`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6787393/312312), or by retaining the instance of the fragment, [using the `setRetainInstance`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11160506/312312)

Comment: I have provided links for both. Click on the links and read them