# Screen orientation change with setRetainInstance(true)

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Hey I would like to ask how to handle screen orientation change in android with the new method setRetainInstance(true) given that it only works with fragments that are not added to backstack. What I currently have is an app which does not use fragments it only uses an activity and uses asynctasks so how would I go about implementing this new change in android in my app 
This solution is not viable since I need the layout to change from landscape to portrait android:configChanges="orientation"

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the guides and docs about activitys and fragments
[Saving instance state](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState)

Comment: how can we retain configuration changes in fragments which are maintain in back stack. As we cannot use `setRetainInstance(true)`

Answer (score 0):

You have override two methods 1) onSaveInstanceState() and 2) onRestoreInstanceState().

Save all your dynamic data and objects into bundle and retrieve it onRestoreInstanceState().

For example,

```
  @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putString("message", text.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        message = savedInstanceState.getString("message");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"This solution is not viable since I need the layout to change from landscape to portrait"

The point of a retained fragment is that even though the underlying activity may be destroyed on a configuration change, your fragment will not; therefore you can have it persist state through the change.

These links will help you:

[Understanding Fragment's setRetainInstance(boolean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182180/understanding-fragments-setretaininstanceboolean)

[Why use Fragment#setRetainInstance(boolean)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160412/why-use-fragmentsetretaininstanceboolean)