# ListFragment getListView() returns null after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-listfragment

I call `getListView()` in `OnActivityCreated()` in my `ListFragment`. It works fine, but if I rotate the device screen and call getListView() again it returns null.

This is the ListFragment **code :**

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ListView list = getListView();

        if (list != null) {
            //List is not null!
        }
        else {
            //List is null, there is an error.
        }
    }

}
```

this is the layout xml (**my_list_fragment.xml**):

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should call it in onViewCreated():

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ListView list = getListView();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this?: ListView list=getView().findViewById(R.id.list);

Comment: Does it work if you get the listview instance in onCreateView()? Like View view=inflater.inflate(...); ListView listView=view.findViewById(...); return(view);

Comment: @KfirGuy You should post your solution as an answer so that anyone else with the same problem can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

this was my solution:

in my **ListFragment** I overrode the **onCreate** method like this...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    setRetainInstance(true); // handle rotations gracefully

    ...
}
```

in my **FragmentActivity** I added a tag to the **FragmentManager** in my **onCreate** method like this...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);

    ...

    // create or retrieve the venue list fragment
    final String venueListTag = VenueListFragment.class.getName();
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    VenueListFragment venueListFragment = (VenueListFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(venueListTag);
    if (venueListFragment == null) {
        venueListFragment = new VenueListFragment();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main, venueListFragment, venueListTag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    ...
}
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160412/why-use-fragmentsetretaininstanceboolean) is more about **setRetainInstance** if you're interested. 
Im not sure if the android team frowns upon using **setRetainInstance** but they sure do keep it a secret