# Android oncreateview called twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have see this question asked here more than one time but I can't figure it out how to solve for my case.

I have an app that the user does this:

1 - Open the navigationDrawer and selects one option (a fragment is created) (I'm here selecting the second option);

```
public void selectItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case FRAGMENT_OPTION1:
                ...
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_OPTION2:
                fragment = ControlPanelFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            ...
            case FRAGMENT_OPTIONN:
                ...
                return;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
}
```

2 - The selected option (ControlPanelFragment) gets loaded:
    2.1 - Control panel has tabs and an iconpager. For each pager page and for each tab a new fragment is created. I have 3 tabs and 3 pages so 9 fragments are created;

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        currentControlPanelOption = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentControlPanelOption", currentControlPanelOption);
        currentControlPanelTab = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentControlPanelTab", currentControlPanelTab);
    }
    setControlPanelTabs();
    setIconPager();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("currentControlPanelOption", pager.getCurrentItem());
    outState.putInt("currentControlPanelTab", mTabHost.getCurrentTab());
}
```

3 - In the `setIconPager();` I have this code:

```
pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
cPanelPagerAdapter = new ControlPanelPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
pager.setAdapter(cPanelPagerAdapter);
```

where `ControlPanelPagerAdapter` has this code:

```
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    Fragment fragment;
    switch (index) {
        case 1:
            fragment = FragmentA.newInstance();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = FragmentB.newInstance();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = FragmentC.newInstance();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = null;
            break;
    }
    ...
    return fragment;
}
```

4 - `FragmentA`, `FragmentB` and `FragmentC` have almost the same code:

```
public static FragmentA newInstance() {
    return new FragmentA();
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_placeholder, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentA_Data = new FragmentADetail[3];
        createTabInstance(0);
    } else {
        fragmentA_Data = (FragmentADetail[]) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("Data");
        return;
    }
}
private void createTabInstance(int tab) {
    new FragmentADetail();
    fragment = FragmentADetail.newInstance(tab);

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("tab", tab);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    fragmentA_Data[tab] = fragment;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragmentA_Data[tab]);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
public void getTabData(int tab) {
    if (fragmentA_Data[tab] == null) {
        createStoreTimePeriodInstance(tab);
    } else {
        if (fragmentA_Data[tab].getArguments() == null) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("tab", tab);
            fragmentA_Data[tab].setArguments(args);
        }
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragmentA_Data[tab]);
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("data", fragmentA_Data);
}
```

5 - Finally, `FragmentADetail` has this code:

```
public static FragmentADetail newInstance(int tab) {
    selectedTab = tab;
    return new FragmentADetail();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_fragment, container, false);
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        selectedTab = savedInstanceState.getInt("selectedTab");
    }
    ...
}

public void getTabData(int tab) {
    //This is where I'm getting the data that populates the layout
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("selectedTab", selectedTab);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
       getTabData(args.getInt("tab"));
    }
}
```

Now, imagine I'm on `FragmentA` with the third tab selected. If I rotate the screen I have this sequence of events:

1. ControlPanelFragment `onSaveInstanceState` saves the current tab and current fragment
2. FragmentA `onSaveInstanceState` saves the tabs fragments for the pager
3. navigationDrawer second option gets again called `fragment = ControlPanelFragment.newInstance();`
4. ControlPanelFragment `onViewCreated` is called and I can get the saved data information and a new pager and tabs are created
5. FragmentA `onViewCreated` is called and I can extract the saved data
6. FragmentADetail `onActivityCreated` gets the saved data and loads the data correctelly (at least I think)
   And from now a second set of methods is called the second time and the data that was previously saved is reseted and so it now displays wrong data
7. ControlPanelFragment `onSaveInstanceState` but now the savedInstanceState is null
8. ControlPanelPagerAdapter `getItem` is called instantiating the 3 fragments
9. FragmentA `onSaveInstanceState` its now called but savedInstanceState is null
10. FragmentADetail `onActivityCreated` is called but now the tab = 0

Can someone explain-me how can I stop steps 7 to 10 from happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figure out what was my problem.

When I was doing:

```
case FRAGMENT_OPTION2:
    fragment = ControlPanelFragment.newInstance();
break;
```

I was creating a fragment and when I rotated the screen `selectItem(int position)` was again called so a new instance of the same object was created thus the steps `7` and following. The solution was to check if the fragment was already created and use him instead of creating a new one.
I've saved the initial fragment with a tag and them looked for that tag. If the tag existed, use that fragment otherwise create a new one.

```
public void selectItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case FRAGMENT_OPTION1:
                ...
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_OPTION2:
                fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(position));
                if (fragment == null) {
                    fragment = ControlPanelFragment.newInstance();
                }
                break;
            ...
            case FRAGMENT_OPTIONN:
                ...
                return;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, 
                    String.valueOf(position)).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder, how often I forget about `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG)` before creating a new fragment.