# Retaining Fragment instance (no configuration change) with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, instance, retain

As the title suggests, I want to retain my fragments. I have enforced my app orientation to always be in landscape mode in the manifest file so that there will be no rotations.

I have read:
[Understanding Fragment's setRetainInstance(boolean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182180/understanding-fragments-setretaininstanceboolean)
and
[Why use Fragment#setRetainInstance(boolean)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160412/why-use-fragmentsetretaininstanceboolean)
However, I am not sure if they apply to my situation.

My project consists of a `ViewPager` with swipe tabs. How can I ensure that the fragments used in the ViewPager are the same ones as created when the MainActivity first starts? Would I use the same tagging method and `findfragment` by tag?

Additionally, where would it be best to check for the tagged fragment, else create a new fragment?

Just a side question related to ViewPager: what can I do to immediately create all fragments used in the ViewPager when the `mainactivity` is started, rather than to wait for a swipe event to occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your last question view pager will by default create the fragments around the current fragment so you don't need to worry about that part. What I would recommend is let the view pager manage your fragments for you rather changing the behaviour since you might face performance issues.

`SetRetainInstance` simply keeps the instance of your fragment when its detached so it's up to you to assess whether you need to use it or not.. is there anything you want to maintain about that fragment? if not then do not use it, free your memory as much as possible.

For the last question, why do you want the same fragments created from the first time to be retained ? all the time? if you NEED to do that then rethink your structuring. gracefully recreate your fragments and maybe have some caching of your data on another layer if that is what you are worried about.

Comment: Hi Nilesh/Jay, thanks for you response. It has prompted me to think about whether i really need to retain the fragment instance, and it does seem that it is not a must.

Comment: @ImranHamid no worries accept the answer if you think this answered your questions