# Fragment setRetainInstance() is deprecated. What is the alternative?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Android have deprecated `setRetainInstance ()` of a `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`

```
class HomeFragment: Fragment (){
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: 
      Bundle?){
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

          retainInstance = true//deprecated
     }
}
```

How do I retain the fragment state being that this method is deprecated

**code language KOTLIN**

I've read this thread

**[Why use Fragment#setRetainInstance(boolean)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160412/why-use-fragmentsetretaininstanceboolean)**
it doesn't answer the question.

I've been trying to implement the android documentation recommendation to no avail. what I need is a code snippet of a solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60648432/7666442

Comment: the answer is not there. I've read that before asking.

Comment: WHat are you trying to use it for?  It was always kind of a hack, there's generally better ways of accomplishing whatever it is you want to do.